# SDL Render Text not showing up unless other surface cleared

Tags: sdl, truetype, surface, blit

I have a

```
timer = TTF_RenderText_Solid( tfont, timeStr.str().c_str(), txtColor ); 
applySurface(500, 30, timer, screen);
```

and on the 'screen' surface I have also applied my character, and my wall. But for some reason I can't seem to see the timer unless I have already NULL the 'floorsurface' and the 'charsurface'. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: and i forgot to say, the timers the codes are called from a function from a while loop(not the polling loop) is that the right place? i cant upload the whole thing i have about 300 lines :S

Comment: Would you be able to show your applySurface function code? And can you clarify what the floorsurface and charsurface is? Thanks

Comment: my applySurface would be 
    void applySurface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL )
{
     SDL_Rect offset;
     
     offset.x = x;
     offset.y = y;
     
     SDL_BlitSurface(source, clip, destination, &offset);
}

Comment: sorry that somehow the codes are not appearing correctly and my floorSurface is a surface for clipping a dungeon's map and the charsurface is the character's clipping as well

Comment: Are you making sure that you're blitting the text _after_ you blit all of the other surfaces?

Comment: okay, so in my main(), i first use init() to check if everything initialized okay and then loadfiles() to load the respectivefiles and then, i clipFloors() - clip the dungeon map and then the clipPlayer)- clip the character sprite then once done, its into the main loop a "while(quit == false)" loop.

Comment: in the main loop there is a poll loop and in the main loop i have a me.move()-moving the character and collision detection
me.setFocus() that's for a scrolling effect then i have a 
me.show()-changing the sprite accordingly

Comment: then i have a 
"  if(SDL_Flip(screen) == -1)
    return 1;"

followed by the timerUpdate() -does the description in the initial post above.. do u think my order is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting timerUpdate() before SDL_Flip(screen). You are calling SDL_Flip, then you call timerUpdate(). So you think, OK, that's fine, next time the screen is flipped, I'll see the text. But what is happening is that you are blitting more surfaces on top before the screen is flipped again, and then you can't see the text because you blitted surfaces on top of it. All you need to do is change the order, so

```
timerUpdate();
if (SDL_Flip(screen) == -1) return 1; //Instead of the other way round
```

should work.

Comment: i have tried that, including a function which clears everything away by setting the floorsurface and player to NULL which, makes the screen black. If i do tat, i can see the text but, when the floors are visible, it cant be seen :( im sure i did something wrong but i just dont know what. the flipping u suggested above also does not do anything :(

Comment: ohmahgod! it's visible now! what i did was there was another loop which 'shows' the floor of the dungeon map so the timerUpdate() was moved after that loop! it works now! thanx alot!